# Porque é que o Linqpad diz que uma directoria de Rede existe, enquanto o .NET nao?

Tags: c#, .net, runtime, io

Eu tenho uma directoria de rede em `"\\10.88.0.1\rec"`. Contudo `Directory.Exists` retorna false enquanto estou a debugar no visual studio. Isto é estranho, uma vez que o `LinqPad` retorna `true`.

Há algumas diferencas entre o ambiente de execucao do linqpad, para o ambiente de execucao do visual studio que tenham efeitos nisto? Como posso configurar a minha aplicacao para reconhecer o caminho de rede, de mesma forma que o LinqPad reconhece?

Comment: Por isso que não uso o `Directory.Exists()`, isto sempre foi errado em 99,99% dos casos. Tem diferença, o Linqpad toma conta de muita coisa, cria um ambiente de execução diferenciado para fazer o que se propõe, mas não sei detalhes e nem se isso não foi só coincidência.

Comment: @Maniero E o que devo fazer entao?

Comment: Não faço ideia porque não o uso, mas de qualquer forma o Linqpad deveria ser usado só para alguns testes rápidos, em produção o código deve ser mais robusto mesmo.